# RoboSpice RequestProgress gets updated but requestSuccess is not called

Tags: android, rest, android-networking, robospice

I have a simple demo for RoboSpice running.

It is the default service that extends `SpringAndroidContentService`, as found on their github.

The weird thing is, when I send a request, the `Progress` gets updated, but I eventually don't get the call to `onRequestSuccess`, which is a simple Toast.

I checked LogCat, and there is no exception. Here is the relevant code:

```
/* RestContentRequest overrider */
@Override
public String loadDataFromNetwork() throws Exception {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = getRestTemplate();
    try {
        String response= restTemplate.getForObject(
            "http://xxx.xxx/mobile.html", String.class);
        //does not get called
        Log.d(LOGTAG, response); 
        return response;
    } catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
        //Does not get called
        Log.e(LOGTAG, e.toString());
        return e.getLocalizedMessage();
    }
}

private class RequestListener implements RequestListener<String>, RequestProgressListener {

    @Override
    public void onRequestFailure(SpiceException exception) {
        //Does not get called
        debug.setText(exception.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestSuccess(String response) {
        //Does not get called
        Toast.makeText( LoginActivity.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestProgressUpdate(RequestProgress progress) {
            //Gets called
            debug.setText(convertProgressToString(progress));
    }

    private String convertProgressToString( RequestProgress progress ) {
        String status = "";
        switch ( progress.getStatus() ) {
            case READING_FROM_CACHE:
                status = "? cache -->";
                break;
            case LOADING_FROM_NETWORK:
                status = "^ network ^";
                break;
            case WRITING_TO_CACHE:
                status = "--> cache";
                break;

            default:
                status = "";
                break;

        }
        return status;
    }

}
```

What could be the cause of this? It simply has to read a page with a string on it. (plain/text)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which version of RoboSpice you tried this on, but it should definitely work with RoboSpice. Would you mind to give it a try ? The last stable version is 1.3.1.

And you have a RoboSpice question on Stack Over Flow, please notify me or tag it.

Comment: I eventually fixed this by moving from Jackson libraries to Gson libraries. Still don't know if the issue relies in that version of RoboSpice, or the Jackson libraries. I will download the latest version and notify you.

Comment: thx @tolgap. Use RoboSpice issue page more than SOF. But it was nice to see the first Stack Over FLow question about RoboSpice yesterday ;)